# Is every token on ethereum tradable on EtherDelta?

Tags: ether, tokens, myetherwallet, etherdelta

Is every token on ethereum tradable on EtherDelta given that there is atleast 1 buyer and atleast 1 seller interested?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can import any custom token as long as it is ERC20-compliant and trade it. But to be part of the "official" supported tokens (so you can select it in the drop-down list of tokens) you need to ask etherDelta to list it.

See also this [Statement by Etherdelta](https://www.reddit.com/r/EtherDelta/comments/6hrwnu/etherdelta_is_a_decentralized_exchange/dky75cz/) on reddit.

Comment: "you need to ask etherDelta to list it" - you as in the contract owner?

Comment: Theoretically anyone can ask to get a token added, as all necessary information (contract address, decimals) is publicly available. I don't know if/what policy etherdelta has in place to add a token to their list.